# Migrating CodeIgniter from WAMP to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS LAMP

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu, lts

After I successfully installed [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) LAMP on my local machine, following this [TUT](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu). And installed phpmyadmin with this [instruction](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04/). I migrated my working CodeIgniter project inside /var/www/ and updated my database. Everything seems to be working fine except i'm having a 404 error saying:

```
GET http://192.168.1.11/quantum/login/ 404 (Not Found)
The following error occured: error Not Found
GET http://192.168.1.11/quantum/user/ 404 (Not Found)
The following error occured: error Not Found
```

After hours of desperate troubleshooting I found some possible causes.

1. .htaccess (already updated)

`RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]`

2. mod_rewrite (already enabled)

but still, i cant seem to make it work. any ideas? is there more to be configured to make the project running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to reconfigure my htaccess by allowing override on my httpd.conf inside apache2.

```
<Directory /var/www/quantum>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Works like peanut butter and jelly.

Answer (score 0):

1. (dumb) Have you checked all folders have successfully been copied?
2. Have you changed your `base_url` in the config file? (/application/config/config.php)
3. When mod_rewrite is enabled (to remove the index.php in the URL), your `index_page` item in the config file must be blank.

If you have already checked these things, try disabling `mod_rewrite` in order to track if this is your issue.